# Narrow type of Prisma select return type

Tags: typescript, types, prisma

I have the following Prisma schema:

```
model Example {
    id        String   @id @default(cuid())
    createdOn DateTime @default(now())
    type      String
}
```

`type` should ONLY be one of the following values:

```js
const Types = [
  "createdLicense",
  "archivedLicense",
  "updateProcessingType",
  ...
] as const;
```

I'm using Prisma with an MSSQL database so I can't use Prisma's enums. On inserts I use the `satisfies` operator to make sure I don't have any typo in my type.

```js
type: "archivedLicense" satisfies HistoryType,
```

This works *fine* it's not perfect but good enough for me. The problem is with select statements, since the return type of the `type` field will be `string` which is too broad.
I have thought about extending the Prisma client, but my current solution does not work:

```js
type HistoryType = (typeof Types)[number];
const custom = prisma.$extends({
  name: "example",
  query: {
    example: {
      // narrow the return type so that the field `type` is of type HistoryType
      async findMany({ model, args, operation, query }) {
        const queryResult = await query(args);
        return queryResult.map((item) => {
          return {
            ...item,
            type: item.type as HistoryType,
          };
        });
      },
    },
  },
});
```

The return type is still `string`.

Comment: It isn't possible to do it like such, the best you can do is define your own method on the model. Would that be an acceptable solution? If so, I'll write up an answer. Just to note, it's not the most elegant solution, but it'll work. Otherwise, you can add an `as` assertion in all the places.

Comment: I see. If it's really impossible you can write a solution with your method.

Comment: You could have also used a Prisma `enum` for this field instead of a string.

Comment: @Shadoath `enum` was at the time of writing unavailable for MSSQL. That still seems to be the case today: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/database-features#misc

> I'm using Prisma with an MSSQL database so I can't use Prisma's enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

Like mentioned in the comment above, it's not the most elegant solution, but it'll work, and I know you're probably aren't going to like it, because it involves a lot of types customization from `prisma`, so I'll explain each type and build upon it for the final result.

---

#### First Step

Firstly, since your requirement is to be able to have some particular set of strings be available as literal types through intellisense, we'll need a type that'll allow us to use any string and still give us intellisense for certain chosen strings, you can do it like this -

```ts
type StringWithAutocomplete<T> =
  | T
  | Omit<string & Record<never, never>, keyof string>;

type UserNames = "John" | "Bobby" | "Jack" | "Tony";

// Will give intellisense for all the UserNames
let a: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> = "something else";

// Will give intellisense for all the UserNames
let b: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> = "Bobby";
```

And this is how it'd look -
[image: autocomplete]

So, we are able to get intellisense for strings and still are able to assign any string to a variable not just the defined literal types. We'll make use of this to create our own custom types using some prisma types.

---

#### Building out types for method: findManyCustom

To build our `findManyCustom` we'll have to introspect the types on `findMany` of our model. I took the prismas' official docs [quickstart](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart) example to build upon with model for a `User` -

```ts
model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  name  String
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}
```

Our method `findManyCustom` will have intellisense for a `User`'s `name` field. First, we'll start with typing for the `where` input parameter. For that we'll have to check the types of `findMany` as mentioned before and use all that's provided by `prisma` and customize the `name` field in all the places -

```ts
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import type { Types } from "@prisma/client/runtime/library";

type StringWithAutocomplete<T> =
  | T
  | Omit<string & Record<never, never>, keyof string>;

type UserNames = "John" | "Bobby" | "Jack" | "Tony";

// Type for findMany({where: })'s where input
type CustomUserWhereInput = {

  // recursive type
  AND?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];

  // recursive type
  OR?: CustomUserWhereInput[];

  // recursive type
  NOT?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];

  // from prisma's definition of `findMany`
  id?: Prisma.IntFilter<"User"> | number;

  // from prisma's definition of `findMany`
  email?: Prisma.StringFilter<"User"> | string;

  // customized with our types, where CustomUserModelStringFilter is a replacement of
  // Prisma.StringFilter, to make sure the name field gives us intellisense in all the places
  // CustomUserModelStringFilter defined down below
  name?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | CustomUserModelStringFilter;

  // from prisma's definition of `findMany`
  posts?: Prisma.PostListRelationFilter;
};

// Used above in CustomUserWhereInput
// In this type, all instances of type string are replaced with our
// StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> type, everything else is from prisma
type CustomUserModelStringFilter = {
  equals?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  in?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>[];
  notIn?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>[];
  lt?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  lte?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  gt?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  gte?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  contains?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  startsWith?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  endsWith?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  not?: CustomUserModelStringFilter | StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>;
};
```

Now, since we're trying to make sure that `name` field in all the places of the API has this intellisense, we'll also need to modify the type for the `cursor` input `findMany` takes, which gives us cursor to get more results like so -

```ts
// Replaced all where input fields with our custom ones, and
// used StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> instead of string
// everything else is from prisma
type CustomUserWhereUniqueInput = Prisma.AtLeast<
  {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    AND?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
    OR?: CustomUserWhereInput[];
    NOT?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
    name?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | CustomUserModelStringFilter;
    posts?: Prisma.PostListRelationFilter;
  },
  "id" | "email"
>;
```

Everything in prisma is typed, and to give you such great typings they make use of some awesome utilities that determine the output type, based on all the arguments we provide, one such type is `GetResult` which takes the type of models (model payload type) in a sense essentially, and another type parameter which is of the type of argument provided to the function, based on that this, utility provides you with the result. To make sure we get correct typings with this, we need to type our own model payload type like so -

```ts
// We only replace string type with our StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>
// rest remains same from prisma
type CustomUserPaylod = {
  name: "User";
  objects: {
    posts: Prisma.$PostPayload[];
  };
  scalars: Types.Extensions.GetResult<
    {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>;
    },
    Types.Extensions.Args["result"]["user"]
  >;
  composites: {};
};
```

Next step is to create typings for the argument that goes into `findMany`, in which we replace the `where` and `cursor` type and let everything else remain same -

```ts
type CustomUserFindManyArgs = {
  select?: Prisma.UserSelect | null;
  include?: Prisma.UserInclude | null;
  where?: CustomUserWhereInput;
  orderBy?: Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput | Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput[];
  cursor?: CustomUserWhereUniqueInput;
  take?: number;
  skip?: number;
  distinct?: Prisma.UserScalarFieldEnum | Prisma.UserScalarFieldEnum[];
};
```

Now, we'll need to make our `findManyCustom` method available on our `prisma.user` model, for that we'll have to do [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). -

```ts
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import type { Types } from "@prisma/client/runtime/library";

declare module ".prisma/client" {
  namespace Prisma {
    export interface UserDelegate {
      findManyCustom: <T extends CustomUserFindManyArgs>(
        args?: Prisma.SelectSubset<T, CustomUserFindManyArgs>
      ) => Prisma.PrismaPromise<
        Types.Result.GetResult<CustomUserPaylod, T, "findMany">
      >;
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Putting it all together

We're almost done now, all that we need to do is define our function. This snippet of code will contain all the types we've built above and would be a working example -

```ts
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import type { Types } from "@prisma/client/runtime/library";

type StringWithAutocomplete<T> =
  | T
  | Omit<string & Record<never, never>, keyof string>;

type UserNames = "John" | "Bobby" | "Jack" | "Tony";

type CustomUserModelStringFilter = {
  equals?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  in?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>[];
  notIn?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>[];
  lt?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  lte?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  gt?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  gte?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  contains?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  startsWith?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  endsWith?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | Prisma.StringFieldRefInput<"User">;
  not?: CustomUserModelStringFilter | StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>;
};

type CustomUserWhereInput = {
  AND?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
  OR?: CustomUserWhereInput[];
  NOT?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
  id?: Prisma.IntFilter<"User"> | number;
  email?: Prisma.StringFilter<"User"> | string;
  name?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | CustomUserModelStringFilter;
  posts?: Prisma.PostListRelationFilter;
};

type CustomUserWhereUniqueInput = Prisma.AtLeast<
  {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    AND?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
    OR?: CustomUserWhereInput[];
    NOT?: CustomUserWhereInput | CustomUserWhereInput[];
    name?: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames> | CustomUserModelStringFilter;
    posts?: Prisma.PostListRelationFilter;
  },
  "id" | "email"
>;

type CustomUserFindManyArgs = {
  select?: Prisma.UserSelect | null;
  include?: Prisma.UserInclude | null;
  where?: CustomUserWhereInput;
  orderBy?: Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput | Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput[];
  cursor?: CustomUserWhereUniqueInput;
  take?: number;
  skip?: number;
  distinct?: Prisma.UserScalarFieldEnum | Prisma.UserScalarFieldEnum[];
};

type CustomUserPaylod = {
  name: "User";
  objects: {
    posts: Prisma.$PostPayload[];
  };
  scalars: Types.Extensions.GetResult<
    {
      id: number;
      email: string;
      name: StringWithAutocomplete<UserNames>;
    },
    Types.Extensions.Args["result"]["user"]
  >;
  composites: {};
};

declare module ".prisma/client" {
  namespace Prisma {
    export interface UserDelegate {
      findManyCustom: <T extends CustomUserFindManyArgs>(
        args?: Prisma.SelectSubset<T, CustomUserFindManyArgs>
      ) => Prisma.PrismaPromise<
        Types.Result.GetResult<CustomUserPaylod, T, "findMany">
      >;
    }
  }
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Adding the definition for our method -
prisma.user.findManyCustom<Prisma.UserFindManyArgs<Types.Extensions.DefaultArgs>> = (args) => {
  return prisma.user.findMany(args);
};
```

Now we've `findManyCustom` method on our `User` model with intellisense for `name` field. Phew!

[image: fndManyCustom-where]

Intelisense for input ⬆️

[image: findManyCustom-result]

Intelisense for result/output ⬆️

Comment: Wow thanks for that. I see that you created type like `CustomUserModelStringFilter` from scratch. I'm guessing that's because there is no way to access the type that is auto generated?

Comment: Actually, all the types created are from scratch, using some default definition from `prisma`. Reason for that isn't that prisma doesn't export the types, it does export almost all of the types (I haven't really tried to check all), and we can surely use type intersection to just override some types that we want, but because of ***intellisense context pollution*** (a term I just coined), it's a bad thing, and that's why I stuck with custom types in all places. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA2KkW) explanation for more details. I don't want to write many long comments explaining.